# Selenium + Java java.io.FileNotFoundException (The system cannot find the path specified)

Tags: java, selenium, automation

I'm trying to run a project that my boss import to me, I change the path of the file but when I run my code keep looking the old path and I don't know what to do. Could you please help?

Here is the screenshot of the error.

[image: error]

Here is my code:

```
String userID;

File srcFile = new File("path");
FileInputStream inputID = new FileInputStream(srcFile);


XSSFWorkbook srcBookID = new XSSFWorkbook(inputID);
XSSFSheet sourceSheetID = srcBookID.getSheetAt(1);

row=row+1;
XSSFRow srcRowID = sourceSheetID.getRow(row);

XSSFCell cell1 = srcRowID.getCell(2);
        cell1.setCellType(XSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_STRING);
userID =cell1.getStringCellValue();
        System.out.println(userID);

return userID;


public String readPassword(int row) throws IOException {
    String password;


    File srcFile = new File("path");
    FileInputStream inputPwd = new FileInputStream(srcFile);

    XSSFWorkbook srcBookPwd = new XSSFWorkbook(inputPwd);
    XSSFSheet sourceSheetPwd = srcBookPwd.getSheetAt(1);

    row = row + 1;
    XSSFRow srcRow = sourceSheetPwd.getRow(row);

    XSSFCell cell1 = srcRow.getCell(3);
    cell1.setCellType(XSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_STRING);
    password = cell1.getStringCellValue();
    System.out.println(password);


    return password;
}
```

Comment: Does the path exist? Have you checked that?

Comment: yes actually i have created the path that is looking for but error continues :( and change the path with different one and continues looking the same :(

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to hardcode, because you are calling the same path.

```
String desiredPath = "C:\\yourDesirePath"; 
File srcFile = new File(desiredPath);
```

Answer (score 0):

Clean the project once and Build it again.

and try to get file dynamically

Place the document in resource folder and read the file in using following below code

```
        String FILE_NAME = "somthing.xlsx";

        ClassLoader classLoader = ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader();

        File file = new File(classLoader.getResource(FILE_NAME).getFile());

        FileInputStream excelFile = new FileInputStream(file);
```

Here is the Link that might help you : https://howtodoinjava.com/java/io/read-file-from-resources-folder/